# Javascript inheritance with a priviledged function

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I'm simplifying my example to get to the heart of my question. I have a base Javascript class with a privileged function. I really need to hide myVar from being seen and I also really want to inherit from `baseClass`.

```
function baseClass() {
  var myVar = new coolClass();

  this.myPrivileged = function() {
    myVar.coolFunction();
  }
}
```

The problem I get is that I'm trying to inherit like so:

```
function childClass() {

}
childClass.prototype = new baseClass();
childClass.prototype.reallyCoolFunction = function() {//Really cool stuff}
```

but only one instance of myVar will ever be created and that will not work because `coolClass` has instance dependant properties.
so if I do this:

```
var x = new childClass();
var y = new childClass();
```

both x and y will have the same instance of `baseClass.myVar`

So as far as I can figure I have two choices:

1. Make the `myPrivileged` function a prototype function and expose `myVar`
2. Copy and paste the internals of `baseClass` into `childClass` (which makes me want to gag)

I'm no javascript guru so I was hoping someone would have a good idea.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should look into [coffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/)

Comment: @Kyle: You should at least put some reasons for your comment. Most people are not willing to start using some language that gets compiled into JS and is therefore impossible to debug.

Comment: @JuanMendes "impossible to debug?" No. Not really. That's just your opinion.

Comment: @Kyle your comment was just a comment. CoffeeScript seems useful but doesn't seem to address my question at all.

Comment: @Kyle How do you debug code in CoffeScript, besides using `console.log`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to create an instance of baseClass just to setup inheritance. You're creating an instance of coolClass that is never used. Use a surrogate constructor

```
function childClass() {
  ...
}

function surrogateCtor() {

}

surrogateCtor.prototype = baseClass;
childClass.prototype = new surogateCtor();
```

In your childClass, you need to call the parent's constructor

```
function childClass() {
    baseClass.call(this);
}
```

That will ensure that the base class is initialized every time you instantiate the child class http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/h2ypL/

See my post about inheritance in JS http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/javascript-inheritance-done-right.html